# Custom TextView with just one character that was entered last from keyboard

Tags: android, input, keyboard, textview

Okay, I want somehow do the following.
In dialog I want user to be able to choose one letter (only letters). He should be able to see it after he entered it. If user is not satisfied with his choice he should be able simply click at another letter. And he should see this letter now instead of previous one.

I want to do it with as much standard options as possible.
I think about somehow customise TextView with ability to display only one currently entered character. Or maybe somehow activity or fragment can intercept input from keyboard and then just on every input edit textView with currently entered character.

Can anybody tell me how it can be done?

Comment: Totally missed the infinite loop there! See my edit. I can't test it right now. But the logic seems sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class members

```
private MyTextWatcher mTextWatcher;
private EditText mEditText;
```

Call setTextWatcher() in appropriate place, for example in onCreate

```
public void setTextWatcher()
{
    mTextWatcher = new MyTextWatcher();
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
}
```

MyTextWatcher class

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher
{

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

        String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
        if (text.length() > 1)
        {
            mEditText.removeTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
            mEditText.setText(text.substring(1));
            Selection.setSelection(mEditText.getText(), 1);
            mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to attach a text changed listener to your EditText:

This is kind of a workaround:

```
public class XYZ extends Activity {

String toCompare = "";

....

....

....

yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if (s.length() > 0 && !toCompare.equals(s.toString())) {
                            toCompare = String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));
                            yourEditText.setText(String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)));
                    }

    }

});
```

Comment: Well, I think this should work. However I'm getting Resource not found exception int setText method.

Comment: Can you try replacing `yourEditText.setText(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));` with `yourEditText.setText(String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)));`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708838/textview-settext-resource-not-found-exception?lq=1 You can see that it would have ifinite loop with your code.

Comment: Nope. Just more exceptions.

07-18 01:21:09.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1522): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
07-18 01:21:09.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.startEndAndLength(AbstractStringBuilder.java:216)
07-18 01:21:09.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.replace0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:446)
07-18 01:21:09.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):  at java.lang.StringBuffer.replace(StringBuffer.java:682)

Comment: Made some changes. The string `toCompare` is initialized to "". When user inputs a character, the check `(s.length() > 0 && !toCompare.equals(s.toString())` evaluates to true. This updates `toCompare` with the character and then sets the `EditText`. As soon as the `EditText` is set, onTextChanged is called. But this time, `(s.length() > 0 && !toCompare.equals(s.toString())` evaluates to false. Application waits for user input.

Comment: Well, I see what you are trying to do here, but this is not working either.
String in editable can be for example o____f, where f is previous value and o is currently entered value and _ means just blank spaces. I don't know why it like that, but it would mean that we would always get not the currently inputed char, but only character that was entered first. I've tried to replace s.length() - 1 to just 0. But this not working always, because somehow what we have in editable is unpredictable.

Comment: I'll give it a try later on today, when I can actually test it. Just to be clear, you have an `EditText` and you need it to always display the last character input by the user. So, if the current value of ET is 'a' and user inputs 'b', the value of ET is 'b'(not "ab").