# TextView setText Resource not found exception

Tags: android, exception, textview

I'm getting a `ResourceNotFoundException` and I don't know why.

```
        mTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)));
                mTextView.setText("bla-bla");
            }
        }

    });
```

LogCat:

```
07-17 23:24:11.011: E/AndroidRuntime(15696): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x74
07-17 23:24:11.011: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
07-17 23:24:11.011: E/AndroidRuntime(15696):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3769)
```

When I use `setText` not in this `onTextChanged` method it's working fine.
Why am I getting this exception?

EDIT

Even If I will somehow manage to get knowledge about this error I will have ifinite loop in afterTextChange method. Because I'm editing text in this method.

This question is related to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706172/custom-textview-with-just-one-character-that-was-entered-last-from-keyboard/17706771?noredirect=1#comment25808190_17706771)
So please, help me.

Comment: you are going to need to provide more information that that

Comment: You are probably setting an int to the `TextView` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Look for the "caused by" part in the Locat

Answer (score 1):

You will also run in an infinite loop after you fix your error as you are calling settext in text changed

Comment: good catch but this should probably be a comment as it does not answer the question he asked

Comment: @tyczj He doesn't have enough rep to leave a comment ;)

Comment: @ZouZout not anymore ;)

Comment: Good point, it will be a loop indeed I think.
But how to achieve my goal, which I've described in that question if not this way?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706172/custom-textview-with-just-one-character-that-was-entered-last-from-keyboard/17706771?noredirect=1#comment25808190_17706771

Comment: If you want to set text in after text changed, then simply use a flag. like IgnoreEvent, set it to true before you settext in aftertextchanged method. put all of your code in a block like this if(!IgnoreEvent) { IgnoreEvent = true; // SET TEXT HERE } IgnoreEvent = false; and after that, nothing will happen in the aftertextchanged method